# What should I use instead of "var" in this context? (As "var" is now deprecated)

Tags: solidity

First, I apologize as this question has been asked before; however, the solutions didn't seem to work in the context of my contract.  When I remove "var", Remix does not recognize "car", but with it, I get the warning that "var" is deprecated.  I've tried using "struct car" and "struCar", but neither worked.  How should I replace var?

```
mapping(uint => Vehicle) vehicles;


function newCar(bytes32 _color, bytes32 _make, uint32 _year) public returns (uint ID) {
    var car = vehicles[carID];
    car.color = _color;
    car.make = _make;
    car.year = _year;
    carID ++;
    ID = carID;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `var` with the actual type:

```
Vehicle car = ...;
```

Comment: Hmm.  With that I get "Warning: Variable is declared as a storage pointer.  Use an explicit "storage" keyword to silence this warning".  So can I enter "Vehicle storage car =" ?  Also, is there anything bad about pointing to storage?

Comment: To silence the warning, use `Vehicle storage car = ...`.

Comment: Okay, thank you.  But just curious.  Why does it warn me that it points to storage?  Is this because storage is expensive and it wants to make sure I intended it for storage?

Comment: It's just to prevent mistakes. `uint256 x` is in memory, while `Vehicle y` is in storage. Storage is the rare case, and being explicit tells the compiler you know what's happening.